# Does ASP.net MVC support a Page_Load event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.net MVC .

To start learning on MVC,i was going through a tutorial on MVC, where they used Page_Load event which is same as in Web forms.

Does MVC Supports events,if so what events are supported.

Please Clarify me about this..

Comment: what do yopu want do in the page_load? possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090934/mvc-equivalent-of-page-load

Comment: No - ASP.NET MVC doesn't have a page lifecycle like classic Webforms has.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "page" in the conventional sense in MVC. Your "page" that the end user sees is made up of a View, a controller and optionally a model. There is no server-side 'page' per se. The logic that you would put in page_load in webForms may go in the corresponding controller actions, but the clean separation of concerns in MVC means there may actually be a better place for this behaviour to live anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ,i was going through a tutorial on MVC, where they used Page_Load
>   event which is same as in Web forms.

You could forget about this tutorial. Things like events and Page_Load are not used in an ASP.NET MVC application. You were probably looking at a tutorial about classic WebForms.

You may get started with ASP.NET MVC at the official page: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: Hi Darin..This is the page where i found it..http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx

Comment: @Avinash I see practically no mention of `Page_Load` in Scott's post, only in the comments.

Comment: @Avinash, where did you even see Page_Load in this tutorial? If you are using the WebForms view engine, bear in mind that you don't even have a code behind file as in classic WebForms application. There's no even a notion of Page in ASP.NET MVC. There are Models, Views and Controllers. Bear in mind that this tutorial was written before ASP.NET MVC was released, so there might be some inconsistencies.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov : In the article, see the sub heading , rendering Approach 2 , using Server side controls. i was even suprised to see server controls being used. can you please clarify me on this..ia m pretty much confused

Comment: Yeap, I saw it. This is wrong. As I said this article was written before the actual ASP.NET MVC was released. There's no such thing as Page_Load. I would recommend you reading the official tutorials to get started: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - So we should not use server side controls ,Code behind or any events ..Am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. Forget about any server side controls, code behind and events.

Comment: @Darin :Thank You.this question may be off topic, i would like to know what controls can be used for data binding ,instead of grid views as in case of classic web forms , i am very strong user of grid views. I am confused to what control could fit in for grid view incase of MVC..

Comment: You could use the built-in WebGrid helper. Or use third party helpers such as KendoUI which offers lots of available widgets.

Comment: One more doubt Darin , i think we can not even use ASP.net Ajax for MVC, how to deal with Ajax in MVC ? Do we need to write our own Ajax calls ?

Comment: Of course that you have to write your own calls. jQuery is a pretty popular javascript framework that you could use for this task.